# Is it possible to have a semi-async ajax call in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I'm working on a site that involves looping through an array, using a jQuery ajax call for each element. Here is a simplified version:

```
var myArray=new Array("El1","El2","El3","El4");
for(var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++){
     $.ajax({
         url: 'page.php?param='+myArray[i],
         success: function(data){
               //doing stuff with the data
               //this needs to complete before the loop advances
         }
     });
 }
```

I need each call to complete before advancing through the loop. I tried setting `async:false`, which makes the loop work correctly, but that holds up the rest of the page's scripts and causes a lot of lagging. Is there some way that I can prevent the loop from advancing until the call is complete, but still be able to run other scripts asynchronously?

Comment: Just make one ajax call. Making n small ajax calls is inefficient as hell

Comment: Raynos has a good point, although your business logic may require otherwise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var idx = 0;
var urls = ["El1","El2","El3","El4"];

var doNextRequest = function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'page.php?param=' + urls[idx],
        success: function(data) {
            // ...
            idx++;
            if (idx < urls.length) {
                doNextRequest();
            }
        }
    });
}

doNextRequest();
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no need for a loop if you make use of `Array.shift`:

```
var myArray = new Array("El1", "El2", "El3", "El4");

function doRequest() {
    if (!myArray.length) return;
    var current = myArray.shift();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'page.php?param=' + current,
        success: function(data) {
            //doing stuff with the data
            doRequest();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind this assumes you don't need to keep the item in the array after the call is made, which depending on your needs, may be desirable or not.

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately, I do need to keep the array, but +1 because I like the simplicity of this one

Answer (score 1):

Call the next request in the success-handler of the previous. Something like this. (Could be a more elegant construct for this).

```
var myArray=new Array("El1","El2","El3","El4");
var i = 0;

function callAjax()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: 'page.php?param='+myArray[i],
        success: function(data){
            //doing stuff with the data
            //this needs to complete before the loop advances       

            if (i < myArray.length)
            {
                i++;
                callAjax();
            }
        }
    });
}
```